# I am upgrading to MSAL 2.X in knock application hence token got generated but the defined values are not binding in knockout

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-msal

I am upgrading to MSAL 2.X in knockout application hence token got generated but the defined values are not binding kindly help me MSAL 2.X it will work in Knockout application or not

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create the main myMSALObj instance
// configuration parameters are located at authConfig.js
const myMSALObj = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

let username = "";

/**
 * A promise handler needs to be registered for handling the
 * response returned from redirect flow. For more information, visit:
 * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/acquire-token.md
 */
myMSALObj.handleRedirectPromise()
    .then(handleResponse)
if(handleredirectpromose)
{if(token!=null)
{viewID's {test=#test}
}

}
}

    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
after getting the token, {viewID's {test=#test} this values not bindig
```

Comment: Please correct the formatting and the bracketing of your answer using the formatting possibilities we supply. At the moment, your code is invalid.